# How to approach breadcrumb structure for non-existent page in hierarchy?

Tags: navigation, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to assess the options for creating a breadcrumb component for app that I'm working on. The thing that I'm finding tricky is that the structure of the navigation of the site uses dropdown groups that don't have a corresponding page. For example, we have a set of links that are grouped in a dropdown like this:

| Identify⌄ |
| --- |
| channels |
| links |
| notifications |

So ideally the breadcrumb will be:

home / identify / channels / channel name / settings

but Identify isn't an actual page so I'm not sure what the best option is. From the research that I have done these are the options:

1 - Create a page for Identify. But this seems like creating a page just for the sake of the breadcrumb.

2 - Include Identify in the breadcrumb but don't make it clickable. From what I gather this is a no no.

3 - Don't include Identify in the breadcrumb, so it would be: home / channels / channel name / settings

4 - Have a sideways style breadcrumb where Identify is a dropdown. (This is my favoured one at the moment)

Thoughts please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You don't

**Breadcrumbs correspond to existing pages.** The confusion might arise because there is an action involved, which creates a pathway. However, **this action is not a part of the architecture itself.**

**Take this analogy:** Imagine constructing an amusement park. You begin at the entrance, then develop a section for family attractions. Within this section, you create a smaller area for children up to 12 years old, and in this space, you arrange games for either groups or individuals.

The process above resembles creating breadcrumbs, but the methods for constructing these attractions are irrelevant.

In your case, the *'Identify'* action is merely an interaction element and nothing more.

Thus, your breadcrumb should be:

```
home / channels / channel name / settings
```